# Simple way of accessing dependent property inside custom data annotation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have the following properties on my `DomainRegistry` model:

```
    [Domain("Extension")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select extension")]
    public string Extension { get; set; }
```

Domain it's my custom data annotation and I've tryed everything on my `IsValid` method to access the value inside extension property.

I have the following in my custom data annotation:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class DomainAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string ExtensionProperty { get; set; }

    public DominioAttribute(string property)
    {
        ExtensionProperty = property;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value);
        var extension = (string) properties.Find(Propriedade, true).GetValue(value);
        if (extension == null) return new ValidationResult("Extension shouldn't be null");
        return null;
    }
```

I can't seem to get the value from extension inside `IsValid` method. Anyone have any tip on how to do that? Also I need to get extension as a string value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
        var field = containerType.GetProperty("Extension");

        if (field != null)
        {
            var extensionValue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            return extensionValue != null ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult("Extension shouldn't be null", new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly the solution I've found.

Comment: Although valid, I would suggest using the validationContext.ObjectType instead of validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType(), as this information has been made available.

Answer (score 1):

The `IsValid` method's `value` parameter contains the actual value of the annotated property so in your case the value of the `Name` property. To access the actual `DomainRegistry` instance (to get the value of the `Extension` property) you should use the `validationContext.ObjectInstance` property:

```
 protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
 {
     PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
     var extension = (string)properties.Find(ExtensionProperty, true).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
     if (extension == null) return new ValidationResult("Extension shouldn't be null");
     return ValidationResult.Success;
 }
```

Comment: Still I've found a way of doing that: `string extension = (string) validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(ExtensionProperty).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);`