# How to validate document type using FileValidationAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this Dto class for the web api controller in .NET Core 2.2 MVC.

`ApplicationDocumentType` is an enum

```
public class DocumentUploadDto
{
    [FileValidation]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public enum ApplicationDocumentType
{
    BANKSTATEMENT,     
    NRIC
}
```

and the below class implements the `[FileValidation]`

```
public class FileValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var file = value as IFormFile;

        // some code removed for brevity
        if (!AllowMimeTypes.Contains(file.ContentType))
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Invalid file type.";
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }        
}
```

Now I need to validate based on `DocumentType`. How do I pass `DocumentType` into `FileValidationAttribute` to do some validation?

Currently all `DocumentType` is having the same validation. But now I need to customize the validation based on `DocumentType`.

Thanks Richard for the clue, but I just keep getting the first enum value.

```
public class FileValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var containerType = validationContext.ObjectType;
        var documentType = containerType.GetProperty("DocumentType");

        var file = value as IFormFile;

        if (file == null)
            return new ValidationResult("No file found.");

        if (documentType != null)
        {
            var documentTypeValue = documentType.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (documentTypeValue.ToString() == "NRIC"
            && file.ContentType == "application/pdf")
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Invalid file type. Pdf file type is not allowed for NRIC.";
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        // some code removed for brevity purpose.
    }

}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7954204/124386) what you're looking for? The `ValidationContext.ObjectInstance` property should return the instance of your `DocumentUploadDto` class which is being validated.

Comment: `validationContext.ObjectInstance` will refer to `DocumentUploadDto` in this case, from there it's easy to achieve what you want.

Comment: @RichardDeeming, thanks for the clue. I can get `DocumentType` now. But, not sure why am I keep getting the first enum value. I have updated my original post

Answer (score 1):

If document type is static, you can simply add an attribute to your Attribute.

```
    public class FileValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public FileValidationAttribute(params string[] allowMimeTypes)
        {
            AllowMimeTypes = allowMimeTypes;
        }
        public string[] AllowMimeTypes { get; }
        
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var file = value as IFormFile;

            // some code removed for brevity
            if (!AllowMimeTypes.Contains(file.ContentType))
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Invalid file type.";
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }        
    }
```

and then, in Dto, add allowed Mime Types

```
    public class DocumentUploadDto
    {
        [FileValidation("text/javascript", "text/html")]
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

If you need to pass mime type dynamically, then I suggest looking at https://fluentvalidation.net/ which allows you to easily add data to validation context and write more fluent validators.